# Excel 2007 or 2010 copy/paste without merging cells & with shift all down

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

Let say I have an excel sheet with structure like

[image]

I select a few cells (at one column) and click `Ctrl+C`. After that I want to paste it. I select one cell(B116):

[image]

And click `Ctrl+V`. It gives me an error:

[image]

Excel think that I need to copy just one column or merge it. But I want excel just to create a few rows and moving all content down. How can I do it?

Comment: Dave, thanks for editing. I haven't enough reputation...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, confuses Excel. When you paste an array by selecting one cell (and the pasted area goes into a merged cell), Excel does not know how you want the information pasted into the cells. If you highlight the same number of cells as the copied array, Excel will not have a problem and will paste the information.

Comment: I know it. How can I avoid confuse of excel?

Comment: You didn't read my answer: **select the same size of array that you copied**.

Comment: Do you mean I need to insert much rows before paste? This is my trouble! I have many copy-paste operations and don't wont to insert rows before each paste

Comment: I believe that Excel looks to see if there is anything in the cells, if so, it will ask if you want to shift down, up right or left before pasting.

Comment: It didn't ask me to shift down

Comment: Ok, then you need to select Insert from the File menu, then Cells.

Comment: It ask me "This operation will cause some merged cells to unmerge. Do you wish to continue?"

Comment: LDC, please help me, I have a huge information...

Comment: It is fine for the cells to unmerge, you can always merge them back.

Answer (score 0):

`Copy` the **rows** you want added, then use <kbd>CONTEXT MENU</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> to `Insert Copied Cells`.  In this case, since you have the rows copied and not just the cells, Excel will insert the copied rows into your table while retaining the formatting and structure of your table as-is.  Then, select the cells you want to be blank and simply hit <kbd>DEL</kbd>.

The reason you want to do the above rather than only insert the cells you want copied is because by inserting only those cells, you need to displace the original gride either down or to the left; either of these will break your current table's structure and/or subsequent row alignments.  By inserting the whole row, you retain the structure and formatting and can easily change the cell's contents/data as desired.  You can also enforce a habit of leaving a few blank rows near the top or bottom for the purpose of having a "template" row to copy from.  Alternatively, after you insert your rows, you can copy from another cell and paste that directly instead of inserting, since your table structure is already modified (i.e., don't insert again the individual cells, as this would again displace them).

PS: If you have cells on the right-hand end of the rows that you did **not** want copied over (*including* formatting, such as cell borders, etc.), then after you insert the rows, you can just highlight them and enter <kbd>CONTEXT MENU</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, then choose to displace laterally.